# CSS image z-index image border - create image slider with frame around image and two navigation buttons

Tags: html, css, image

I would like to create an image slider with image border, and changing images to look like the screenshot.

[image: image slider with arrows as navigation buttons and black frame]

My html

```
<div id="slideshow"><span class="control" 
        id="leftControl" style="display: none;">Move left</span> 
    <span class="control" id="leftControl"></span>
    <div id="slidesContainer" style="overflow: hidden;">
        <div id="slideInner" style="width: 3060px;">
            <div class="slide" style="float: left; width: 1020px;">
                <img src="/images/daf.png">
            </div>
            <div class="slide" style="float: left; width: 1020px;">
                <img src="/images/daf.png">
            </div>
            <div class="slide" style="float: left; width: 1020px;">
                3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <span class="control" id="rightControl"></span> 
    <div class="shadow_and_circles">
        <div class="sl1">
        </div>
        <div class="sl2">
        </div>
        <div class="sl1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <span class="control" id="rightControl">Move right</span>
</div>
```

You can find **[the css at my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kot_matpockuh/LjBq4/6/)**. My current result looks like this

[image: layout of image slider components not as expected]

What did i wrong? I have set the z-index, but what else must i do?

#### Update

I created [a new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kot_matpockuh/Xh2KW/1/)

Comment: The code above has some elements that use the same id - for example `id="leftControl"`. An id should be unique within a page. This may lead to additional problems. For instance your css rules may not do what you want them to do.

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree with same id's i know, but problem is not in this and why it can;t be done? see http://htmlbook.ru/css/z-index image

Comment: you demo fiddle is messed up with inline CSS and linked CSS file. Try to clean up your code and you'll see that it is easier to debug. BTW you don't need all containers in absolute position, especially not the parent one.

Comment: @otinanai what do you mean by p with inline CSS and linked CSS file

Comment: I believe i found a solution that is close to what you want. Could you update your answer by uploading your [weblayout3 image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59666091/weblayout3.jpg) and explain what is incorrect? Could you clarify your statment: `note, slider is mostly covering header with negative margin`?
It is unclear to me if you want to understand to solve the layout problem of the html you provided or if you want to find a solution for your whole page (index.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like I said in my comment, your styles are messed up with inline CSS styles and linked classes. Also, there's no need to have all containers in `absolute` position.

[**Here's your demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HG85p/). Is this what you're after?

***_*__*_*__*_*___*EDIT*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**

It seems that you're having `z-index` issues so I've made a demo without using any stack positioning. Just use the classes that I include in the following demo.

**[Demo without `z-index`](http://jsfiddle.net/DtyG5/3/)**.

Comment: yes like this) also i have now something like this, my slider background cover image...  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59666091/wrong.png

Comment: so what do you think?

Comment: I can't debug or provide an answer with just a screenshot. I need the specific piece of code (html/css/js) that generates this issue and most preferably in a fiddle.

Comment: ok, i will give all code, without images... where to send it?

Comment: @PavelBY Just make a fiddle and add it in your OP as an edit.

Comment: i give you this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59666091/temp.zip   it's joomla template in progress, but all code is readable... also with some images )

Comment: No man sorry. The whole point of stackoverflow is to help people and have reference for others to see the problem and the solution. It's not a personal support. Please post ONLY the related fragment of code in a fiddle with as much details possible of the problem you're having.

Comment: @PavelBY Please have a look at my edited answer and if it suits you, please accept it!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kot_matpockuh/Xh2KW/1/  related? hm, if only related, it could be not so clear

Comment: now yes, look's like it must be, just some troubles with that, i have  margin: -210px 0 0 -510px;   so negative, and must change your code.... hm now i edit it, seems not so good, all troubles are of there negative margin

Comment: why are you using negative `margin` and where are you using it?

Comment: in my first fiddle you can see it, i use it for slider, becouse slider must be a little bit on top of the header

Comment: also image on question have a part, see that border is on header, if i will loose margin, it will be after grey-blue line

Comment: @otinanai: It could be that i misunderstood the whole conversation. But i tought OP is looking for a solution to click through several images like in this demo http://www.menucool.com/slider/javascript-image-slider-demo4

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree something like this, but as here http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=1050   and must look here (note, slider is mostly covering header with negatibe margin)  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59666091/weblayout3.jpg

Comment: @PavelBY is the changing of images (the javascript part) already working? 
Is the part that is not working "only" the position and layering of the frame (black), the arrow-images (blue) and the image inside the frame (yellow lorry)?
In the last http://jsfiddle.net/DtyG5/3/ the frame and the images look good to me - what are you missing from this fiddle?

Comment: @PavelBY I don't really understand what is the issue you're having. Please try to include an image in your OP and the full code that generates this issue. Do not just place the Joomla renderer (`<jdoc:include type="modules" name="mainmenu" />`) but instead include all the generated html that it's been produced by Joomla. Also, a link to the actual web project or screenshots would help.

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree "s the part that is not working "only" the position and layering of the frame (black)"  yes!

Comment: @otinanai i use your code, your first edit give's me: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59666091/tr1.png

Comment: @PavelBY if my first edit produces this issue, then use my last edit: http://jsfiddle.net/DtyG5/3/

Comment: as you see bottom of image is visible, but top (where margin get's on header) no

Comment: @otinanai trouble is that second produce same too!

Comment: Your code with images requires me to install the Joomla template in my web server! I hope, you are not expecting me to install a Joomla template, right???? It's obvious that you're facing an issue your template but the slider couldn't interfere with the header in terms of layering because I'm not using z-index at all.

Comment: @otinanai nooo man ))) it's index.php file is just html with css, you could take html from fiddle, paste to some .html file, and append css from zip archive, also there youcould find images ) yo don't need joomla

Comment: but ok, will do all from begining by new(

Comment: @PavelBY From what I've seen in the zip you sent me, you're NOT using my LATEST fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/DtyG5/3/

Comment: @otinanai as i said, i try last edit too, but it is same, when i put there margins

Comment: here you can see full sample and try a little bit dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59666091/csshtml.zip

Comment: Sorry man. I'm not going to help you with zip files. Create a demo/fiddle with all related code and images. Take all the generated html with css and images and upload it in some web server or put it in a fiddle, so that we can see it running in a browser. We are all very happy to help you but you're not helping us. Once again I'm telling you that we don't provide personal support. This is a community and every answer given has to have a thoroughly described problem.

Comment: here is solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102880/image-slider-with-border-as-image-image-in-slider-is-covered-by-background    but i can't accept you answer(  but will do this... even if you are afraid of zip(