# Image slider, with border as image: image in slider is covered by background

Tags: jquery, html, css

I will explain by schema:

grey and white is my background of first div, white is meaned, that this part is transparent.
image border (slider border) is yellow. My image in slider is red.. I need that it works so:

[image: howmustbe]

but i get this:

[image: wrong]

sure, it's only schema, but i think that's it explain what i need.

my code is:

```
<div class='slider'>
      <div class='top_area'>
        <div class='top_area_shadow'>
          <div class='contact'>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id='slideshow'>
        <div id='slidesContainer'>
          <!-- <span class="control" id="leftControl"></span> -->
          <div class="slide">
            <img src="../images/daf.png">
          </div>
          <div class="slide">
            <img src="../images/daf.png">
          </div>
          <div class="slide">
            3
          </div>
          <!-- <span class="control" id="rightControl"></span>          -->        
        </div>        
      </div>
    </div>
```

and css:

```
.top_area{
  height: 80px;
}

.top_area_shadow{
  height: 80px;
  background: url(../images/header_shadow.png);
  background-position: center;
}

.contact{
  position: absolute;
  background: none;
  height: 32px;
  margin-left: -510px;
  margin-top: 32px;
  width: 1020px;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.left_float{
  float: left;
  /*text-align: left;*/
}

.right_float{
  float: right;
  /*text-align: right;*/
}

.slider{
  background: url(../images/slider_bg.png);
  background-position: bottom;
  width:100%;
  height:330px;
}

#slidesContainer {
  width:1020px;
  height:244px;
  overflow:auto;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0px 0 0 -510px;
  position:absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  background: url(../images/border.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}

#slideshow #slidesContainer .slide {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:1020px; 
  height:244px;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
}

.slide img{
  z-index: 1;
  position:absolute;
}

.control {
  display:block;
  width:41px;
  height:40px;
  text-indent:-10000px;
  position:absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#leftControl {
  top:0;
  left:4px;
  background:transparent url(../images/arrow_left.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
#rightControl {
  top:0;
  right:4px;
  background:transparent url(../images/arrow_right.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

image's you can get here:

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59666091/img.zip
```

So:  i need to do slider, where image is under transparent border image (yellow on schema), and if i didn't have any grey background - it works, but with bg - didn't. What i do wrong?

also i try with z-index, but didn't solve it...

If something not clear, write in comments, thank you )

**here you can see full sample and try a little bit dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59666091/csshtml.zip**

Comment: css z-index would be the solution here

Comment: @GertB. i try it, but didn't help!  you could check code with images

Comment: +1 on z-index. Could you post what you tried?  A jsfiddle would be helpful.

Comment: @PavelBY you need to set z-index to the 3 elements, you should indeed show us the css you tried there

Comment: @GertB. did you read question? there is my css! z-index is to

Comment: @Dave jsfiddle is without image's! but i will give link: http://jsfiddle.net/kot_matpockuh/3s4j3/  here it is, but without images, it's pain) so download zip... also i try a lot of z-index combinations

Comment: here you can see full sample and try a little bit dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59666091/csshtml.zip

Comment: also html structure could be a little changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a solution (I tried it on your full sample and it worked):

remove `background-image` from `#slidesContainer` and put image into html as `<img>`:

HTML:

```
 <div id="slideshow">
    <div id="slidesContainer">
       <img src="images/border.png"> <!-- removed from css -->
       <!-- <span class="control" id="leftControl"></span> -->
       <div class="slide">
         <img src="images/daf.png">
       </div>
       <div class="slide">
         <img src="images/daf.png">
       </div>
       <div class="slide">
         <img src="images/daf.png">
       </div>
       <!-- <span class="control" id="rightControl"></span> -->        
    </div>       
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .slider{
  background: url(images/slider_bg.png);
  background-position: bottom;
  width:100%;
  height:330px;
}

#slidesContainer {
  width:1020px;
  height:244px;
  overflow:hidden;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0px 0 0 -510px;
  position:absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#slidesContainer > img{
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0px 0 0 -510px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

#slideshow #slidesContainer .slide {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:1020px; 
  height:244px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#slideshow .slide img {
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

if for some reason that don't work, remove that code and try

```
#slideshow #slidesContainer .slide img {
   z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: here you can see full sample and try a little bit https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59666091/csshtml.zip